# Java: Tomcat 7 Exception loading sessions from persistent storage: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, session, tomcat

After the restart of my Tomcat 7  I am loosing all active sessions.

In the catalina.out file I can see the following:

```
Jan 21, 2017 6:38:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFORMATION: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 21, 2017 6:38:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFORMATION: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 21, 2017 6:38:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMATION: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 21, 2017 6:38:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMATION: Initialization processed in 595 ms
Jan 21, 2017 6:38:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting service Catalina
Jan 21, 2017 6:38:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.56 (Debian)
Jan 21, 2017 6:38:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFORMATION: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT.war
Jan 21, 2017 6:38:11 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFORMATION: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [179] milliseconds.
Jan 21, 2017 6:38:11 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doLoad
SCHWERWIEGEND: ClassNotFoundException while loading persisted sessions: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.mumscasino.core.User
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.mumscasino.core.User
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:628)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1779)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1619)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:1084)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:285)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5534)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1879)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Jan 21, 2017 6:38:11 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager startInternal
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception loading sessions from persistent storage
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.mumscasino.core.User
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:628)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1779)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1619)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:1084)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:285)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5534)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1879)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

de.mumscasino.core.User is a class of my ROOT.war which is used to control all user values in the application. After the startup my application is running without any problems. JSPs and Servlets are able to find this class and work with it. Sessions can be created and closed. After the shutdown of Tomcat I can see the SESSION.ser file created.

I have checked my code. Users implements java.io.Serializable, all fields of this class are boolean, String, int or implements java.io.Serializable also.

In my eclipse IDE with a local Tomcat7 I can restart it without loosing my session. I don't know what I can try to fix now.